# AWS Aurora compatibility with MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

At my company we are considering the possibility to migrate our MySQL dbs to AWS Aurora.

AWS documentation states:

> What does "MySQL compatible" mean?
>
> It means that **most of** the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora **with little** or no change. The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 using the InnoDB storage engine. **Certain MySQL features** like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora.

I haven't been able to find a documentation exhaustively listing which MySQL features are not available with Amazon Aurora, and what kind of "little change" we might have to do if we decide to migrate.

What kind of non-BC change should we expect to encounter if we switch (appart from the non-support of the MyISAM storage engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not expect any change. Most of the innovations of Amazon Aurora are in the storage and replication tiers, the query engine should behave exactly the same and code run unaltered.

However, MySQL is a completely separate development and organization, so it is quite challenging and risky to put compatibility in more precise terms than what you have found. Feel free to ask if there is any feature compatibility in specific you'd like to know more about.